# Android context thread checking

Tags: android, multithreading

As far as I know the UI thread is the main thread.
`getMainLooper` according to the documentation is the UI thread.

The Application context thread shouldn't be the UI thread as well?

Also, the Fragment's Looper thread shouldn't be the UI thread as well?

Why the following fails (both)?

```
if (getActivity().getApplicationContext().getMainLooper().getThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
    throw new Exception("Context is not the application's thread");
}

//Inside a Fragment
if (new Handler().getLooper().getThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
    throw new Exception("Handler is not for the main thread");
}
```

Comment: Context has nothing to do with the Thread, by default any android app has one main UI thread and this is the only thread app is running on

Comment: @pskink I agree, but from the Context it's possible to get the MainLooper and then the Thread it belongs to. Shouldn't this Thread match the UI thread?

Comment: you get the Looper from Looper.myLooper(), not from the Context

Comment: Try using `equals()` instead of `==` and tell us if it changed anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not understand your question but i think my answer makes it clear:

`getActivity().getApplicationContext().getMainLooper().getThread()` returns the thread associated to UI thread or equivalently main thread.

`Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()` also returns above thread. so they both actually one object so the if condition is true that means:

"Context thread **IS** the application's thread"

if you are on main thread then `new Handler().getLooper().getThread()` returns exactly above thread. and also `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()` so the two refrences are actually point to one object so the condition is true and

The handler thread **IS** the main thread

you can easily check those if statements. :-)

`Why the following fails (both)?`

No, i think you get confused the exception meaning. you throw the exception if the condition is true and the condition is true. that is not the same meaning of android exception this is your custom one and it throws correctly because the condition is satisfied.